# Possible bug in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I have the next code:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li ng-repeat="ruta in rutas" >
        <a ng-click="seleccionarDirectorioRuta(ruta)" >{{ruta.nombre}}</a>
    </li>
</ol>
```

the method seleccionarDirectorioRuta:

```
$scope.seleccionarDirectorioRuta = function(directorio){
    alert($scope.rutas.length);
    $scope.directoriosActuales = [];
    $scope.rutas.push(directorio);
    alert($scope.rutas.length);
};
```

In the alerts show 1 and 2 (or n and n+1), but the breadcrumb don't updated.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was getting an error that `ngRepeat` doesn't accept duplicates, but after I used `angular.copy` to make a copy of directorio when pushing into `$scope.rutas` it all worked.

http://plnkr.co/edit/dkIoiql1snvY7oauDNrW?p=preview

```
$scope.seleccionarDirectorioRuta = function(directorio){
    $scope.rutas.push(angular.copy(directorio));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not a bug in Angular. Its because when you run the function, you set the array to be empty for every single run. Without pulling up the code, I'd assume you would want something along these lines:

```
$scope.directoriosActuales = [];
$scope.seleccionarDirectorioRuta = function(directorio){
    alert($scope.rutas.length);
    $scope.rutas.push(directorio);
    alert($scope.rutas.length);
};
```

But since that will likely run wrong, I think the [forEach](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) will help.

Can you let me know if setting the array to none is the reason?

Comment: ng-repeat="ruta in rutas", in this case $scope.directoriosActuales has nothing to do.